# Map Collection to other Collection

Tags: angular, typescript

I have JSON data that contains an collection:

```
"monthlySales": [
    {
        "month": 11,
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "month": 12,
        "value": 1
    }
]
```

I would like to create new collection from it that would contain only `value`s - something like this:

```
let valuesArray = [2, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could benefit from [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) operator:

```
let valuesArray = monthlySales.map(x => x.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it,

```
var newArray = monthlySales.map(function(k,v){return k.value;});
```